# Does find -exec find all results up front, or will it find results added while executing on the previous results?

Tags: shell, find

So if I am downloading say 5000 audio files, each 5 seconds long, and after the first 1000 download, I run:

```
find . -iname "*.wav" -exec play {} \;
```

Will that play only the 1000 files that were present when I first ran the command, or will it play all 5000 files since the files are downloading faster than the exec finishes with them?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the implementation, because [the standard says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> If a file is removed from or added to the directory hierarchy being
>   searched it is unspecified whether or not *find* includes that file in
>   its search.

I think either behaviour may happen, depending on the directory layout and the filesystem behaviour. If, after `find` opens a directory for reading its entries, newly added entries are returned by `readdir`, then `find` will process that too. But that's also unspecified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html):

> If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most
>   recent call to `opendir()` or `rewinddir()`, whether a subsequent call
>   to `readdir()` returns an entry for that file is unspecified.

---

At least with GNU find and BSD find on macOS, the behaviour seems to be to read all entries of a directory at once:

```
% (sleep 5; touch abc) & find . -exec sleep 5 \; -print
[1] 57727
.
[1]  + 57727 done       ( sleep 5; touch abc; )
./foo
./bar
```

Note how it didn't find `abc`. But if the first `sleep` is decreased so that `find` recurses into `.` *after* that `sleep` is over:

```
% rm abc; (sleep 2; touch abc) & find . -exec sleep 5 \; -print
[1] 57971
[1]  + 57971 done       ( sleep 2; touch abc; )
.
./abc
./foo
./bar
```

---

So, if your files are being downloaded into different subdirectories, some files that were downloaded after `find` was run may get played, but some other files may not.

Comment: The only `find` implementation that AFAIK reads directories "at once" is `libfind` from schilytools. Do not confuse blocked directory reading with bulk reading. The mistake you made is to use far too few files for your test.